# Spree Confirmation Emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, testing, spree

So, I want to set up my Spree store such that confirmation emails are not sent when we create orders in the back-end, since we get customers who place orders outside of our store website, which we would like entered into our Spree database nonetheless. The best way we can think of to do this (if you have another way, by all means chime in) is to disrupt this bit of code in the orders model (you can find it at /core/app/models/spree/order.rb):

```
def finalize!
  # lock all adjustments (coupon promotions, etc.)
  all_adjustments.each{|a| a.close}

  # update payment and shipment(s) states, and save
  updater.update_payment_state
  shipments.each do |shipment|
    shipment.update!(self)
    shipment.finalize!
  end

  updater.update_shipment_state
  save!
  updater.run_hooks

  touch :completed_at

  if paid? #THIS CONDITIONAL IS THE BIT WE ADDED
    deliver_order_confirmation_email unless confirmation_delivered?
  end

  consider_risk
end
```

Now it's just a matter of *testing* this. The only kind of payment that can be tested through the GUI is check, and I need to see if this trips with a credit card payment that's been authorized/not authorized/captured/not captured (since Spree's documentation on what qualifies as a payment_state of 'balance_due', 'pending' or 'paid' is pretttty bad). So I've been trying to use factory girl's stuff to make an order like that, and see whether or not a confirmation email has been sent. The only thing I can find for testing confirmation emails, however, involves sending one out, and also I can't find anything that would help me build a factory for an order that specific. Am I missing something?